# How to catch implicit menu 'Back' command?

Tags: java-me, midlet

I'm programming a J(2)ME app (actually a MIDlet) where more commands than command buttons available are shown on the screen and I'm stuck with this situation:

> The mapping to concrete user interface constructs may also depend on
>   the total number of the commands. For example, if an application asks
>   for more abstract commands than can be mapped onto the available
>   physical buttons on a device, then the device may use an alternate
>   human interface such as a menu. For example, the abstract commands
>   that cannot be mapped onto physical buttons are placed in a menu and
>   the label "Menu" is mapped onto one of the programmable buttons.

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Command.html

So in this situation a Menu is auto-generated and a 'Select' and 'Back' choice added. The 'Back' choice is supposed to exit the menu and go back to the previous screen. This works in principle, problem is I need to catch it somehow and trigger a redraw, otherwise the screen goes blank.

So my question is: Is there a way to catch this 'implicit' (automatically added 'Back' command ?

Code example and result:

[image]

```
 public class HelloWorld extends MIDlet
  {
    private Form helloFrm; 
    private Display display;

    public HelloWorld() {
      Command command1 = new Command("Cmd 1", Command.SCREEN, 1);
      Command command2 = new Command("Cmd 2", Command.SCREEN, 0);
      Command command3 = new Command("Cmd 3", Command.SCREEN, 0);
      Command command4 = new Command("Cmd 4", Command.SCREEN, 0);

      helloFrm = new Form("Hello World");

      helloFrm.addCommand(command1);
      helloFrm.addCommand(command2);
      helloFrm.addCommand(command3);
      helloFrm.addCommand(command4);
    }

    public void startApp()
    {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        display.setCurrent(helloFrm);

    }

    public void pauseApp()
    {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
    {
    }
}
```

edit to add more detail:

As per my comment, I'm going back from a Form to Canvas in my app, that's where the screen blanking happens.
I've already added my own 'Back' command, this one works correctly as I can catch easily with CommandListener and treat accordingly (trigger a redraw). But now I have two 'Back' commands, the implicit one (blanking) and mine. 
So the alternative version of the question is: Can I prevent the adding of the implicit 'Back' command somehow ?

Comment: When you say "I need to catch it somehow and trigger a redraw, otherwise the screen goes blank" it looks like your real application is based on Canvas, not Form. Am I right?

Comment: You're absolutely right. In my real app I'm going from Form via 'Back' back to Canvas, that's when the screen goes blank.

Comment: Did you check if sizeChanged or showNotify are called?

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this with a delay. These functions were unknown to me, I checked and showNotify is indeed called when executing the blanking 'Back' command. So that's a good hint, thanks. Problem is though, it's called several times during running the app (e.g. when starting, coming back from another Canvas) so it's not something I can use to handle this specific situation I think. sizeChanged isn't called at all when the extended menu appears.

Comment: You can't prevent the adding of the implicit 'Back' command, but you can  redraw the screen from the call to showNotify.

Comment: Thanks. You can post this as regular answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent the adding of the implicit 'Back' command, but you can redraw the screen from the call to [Canvas.showNotify](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#showNotify()):

> The implementation calls showNotify() immediately prior to this Canvas
>   being made visible on the display. Canvas subclasses may override this
>   method to perform tasks before being shown, such as setting up
>   animations, starting timers, etc. The default implementation of this
>   method in class Canvas is empty.